# normalize the data inside nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I have to normalise the given nested list with the formulae (s-h)/(k-h) where **s** is the values inside nested list and **h** is the value inside minimum of the nested list and **k** is the maximum of that nested list.
For ex here is the sample list `[[1.6,2.2,3.7],[4.8,5.2,3.6][7.1,8.2,9.3]]` which are floating point numbers maximum of this list is `[7.1,8.2,9.3]` and minimum is `[1.6,2.2,3.7]`. So, using the above formulae you will get values between 0 and 1

I tried but I get error here is what I tried

```
def get_normalize_value(score):
 for k, h in zip(maximum[1:], minimum[1:]):
    value = (score-h)/(k-h)
    return round(abs(value))


def get_normalize_data():
 empty_list = []
 for i in normalize_data:
    for f in i:
        empty_list.append(get_normalize_value(f))
return empty_list
```

it should give

> [[0,0.34,0.23][0.24,0.345,0.345][1,0.89,0.435]]

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'list'
```

Comment: How you are performing  `(s-h)/(k-h)` operation? Is it elementwise or taking the sum?

Comment: no actually s is the element inside each every nested list whereas h is inside minimum list and k is the element of maximum list so that as a result I will also get a nested list with values between 0 and 1

Comment: so what are `h` and `k` for above list?

Comment: I said h is the element inside the maximum list of the this nested list

Comment: Can you provide an example calculation for the normalized score for say `s=2.2`, the second element of first sublist

Comment: (2.2-2.2)/(8.2-2.2)

Comment: Then the value is 0, but your answer says 0.34

Comment: You should probably be using pandas for this. Their vector implementations make things like this super efficient.

Comment: Also if you want someone to help you, you will need to add more examples. Your text/current example is way to vague to help you.